# Accessing localhost FTP server via .Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have an MVC application and am trying to access my localhost ftp server I set up in IIS- eventually it'll be accessing some other ftp server but I just want to try it out locally.  I wrote a c# function using FtpWebRequest but when I call GetResponse() it returns the error: "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in." Not sure exactly how to log in as anonymous or non-anonymous user. Is the URL string formatted correctly if I have an FTP site in IIS called "MyFTPSite" and Anonymous Authentication is enabled? What should networkcredential be? The Files directory is a child of ftproot- do I need to add a virtual directory for the Files folder? Right now the physical path of the ftp site is set to C:\inetpub\ftproot. (In below code, localhost purposely spelled wrong b/c the site didn't want me to use a localhost url).

```
 public override bool DownloadFile()
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(this.UrlString);

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.UrlString);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        //anonymous logon
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "<my email>");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        response.Close();
        return true;

    }

FTPDownload download = new FTPDownload(@"ftp://lclhost/MyFTPSite/Files/w4.pdf");
download.DownloadFile();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks like it is probably fine—more than likely you can resolve this by modifying the IIS FTP Server settings.

First, some ideas to get to a base known configuration.

1. Open the IIS Manager tool.
2. Let's ensure you still have `IUSR` as the user that IIS uses for Anonymous Authentication in its internal security scheme. Click on the top node (should be your computer name) in the left sidebar, then click on `Authentication` under the `IIS` section in the main content area. Ensure `Anonymous Authentication` is enabled. Click on this item, then click `Edit` in the right sidebar. Make sure this is already set to `Specific User` with a value of `IUSR`. As long as this is the case, we don't need to get into dealing with the `IUSR` password etc.
3. Click on your FTP site in the left sidebar.
4. In the right sidebar, click `Basic Settings`. Make a note of your directory where the site points-e.g. `C:\inetpub\ftproot`, and ensure this matches up with the expected location of the test file your code is trying to download.
5. In the right sidebar, click on `Bindings`. Since your code doesn't mention a specific port, ensure port `21` is set here. As far as the `IP Address`, leaving it set to `All Unassigned` should be fine, or you can set to `127.0.0.1'.
6. In the main window area, let's go through the settings.

   - `FTP Authentication`: `Anonymous Authentication` should be set to `Enabled`. `Basic Authentication` should be set to `Disabled`. *Hint: use the `<alt>`+`<left>` keyboard shortcut to return to the main list of modules*.
   - `FTP Authorization` : Add an `Allow Rule` as follows: Choose `Specified Users`, and set to `IUSR`. Grant `Read` permission.
   - `FTP IP Address and Domain Restrictions`: Remove any configured rules that show here if you see any. In the right sidebar click `Edit Feature Settings`, then make sure it is set to `Allow` under `Access for Unspecified Clients`. You can leave `Enable Domain Retrictions` unchecked.
   - `FTP SSL Settings`: Check `Allow SSL Connections`. (Enabling `Require SSL connections` is not what you want here.)
7. Ok, now in the left sidebar, right-click on your FTP site and select `Edit Permissions` which will pop open the properties window. Go to the `Security` tab, then you will make some ACL changes if needed. Most importantly, the `IUSR` account needs at least the following: `Read & Execute`, `List folder contents`, `Read`. This will let you your code download files anonymously. You may need to add `Modify` and `Write` for uploading capabilities. To make the change, you may need to disable inheritance from the parent directory—if so, I would recommend copying the existing permissions rather than starting with a blank slate. You may want to use the `Replace all child object permissions...` option if you have made any changes here, to ensure everything from the root down now has the same access control entries.
8. Open an admin command prompt and type `iisreset`

Ok, now that IIS has been configured, let's look at the code. After placing a small text file called `test.txt` in the root of the FTP site, I got the below code, adapted from your sample, to work on my local machine:

```
string ftpHost = "ftp://localhost/test.txt";

FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(ftpHost);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

//anonymous logon
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "test@test.com"); 

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

Console.WriteLine("Download Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

reader.Close();
response.Close();

Console.ReadLine();
```

*[Disclaimer: These instructions are to configure a local FTP server working on a development machine, to allow the .NET FtpClient class to connect to it anonymously. Do not consider these good instructions for use on a Production environment.]*

Comment: Wouldn't ftpHost have to include the name I gave the FTP site, like ftp://localhost/MyFTPSite/test.txt? Went through your steps and still getting same error. I did do what was in step 7, hadn't done that yet for IUSR.

Comment: Hi Kelly, that's correct-in my example, I'm running an FTP site on the default IIS ftp root, so no subdir needed (`ftp://localhost` maps directly to the file dir). The key is that you need the full path to the site/file to be correct. One way to do a quick test of your path and anon setup: open FireFox or Chrome, and try browsing to your FTP root. If it lets you in, then you know the path is right, and the anon security is turned on correctly. In your code try hard-coding the exact path once validated in your web browser. Step through in the debugger, and report any ex you see.

Comment: Also, this is a different scope in the code than what we are discussing, but since your penultimate line in your code example has a literal path that specifies **lclhost** (instead of "localhost"), the above step of hard-coding a known-working path (verified in browser) when you create the `FtpWebRequest` will eliminate the variable of the path being the issue.

Comment: when I go to ftp://localhost it asks me for a username and password- so maybe my anonymous setup is not right?

Comment: Just to verify, did you go in the browser using: `ftp://localhost`? Because if you used `http://localhost`, that would have taken you your root IIS website bound to port 80, which would have it's own security settings. If you did go to `ftp://localhost`, and you're getting prompted for a username, password, then you should take another look at the ACL on that directory. It may be that you could add 'wide' permissions to it, like granting read/execute/list to `Users`, for example.

Comment: Yes I did ftp://localhost, but no luck still. I ended up not needing ftp anymore, perhaps when I get a chance I'll try to get this working but it got put on the back burner. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you set anonymous logon on IIS **do not set** any Network Credentials.
Comment it out:

```
  //anonymous logon
  //  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "<my email>");
```